# Card deck divide for people

Tags: c#, foreach, break

I would divide a deck of french cards for 2-7 people, i start the divide after i break the foreach loop. After i shuffle the deck and do the foreach again in the for loop. But cause i shuffled the deck, i can get the same card at the other hand. So i would divide 5-5 cards for random 2-7 people with the different cards. Is there any way to continue the first foreach where i break it? Then i should not reshuffle the deck.

```
int people = r.Next(2, 8);
int round = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= people; i++)
{
    foreach (Card k in FrenchCard.Cards.Take(5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0,-5} - {1,2}]", k.color, k.figure);
        if (++round == 5) break;  
    }
    FrenchCard.Divide();

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: `Cards.Skip(i * 5).Take(5)`

Comment: It's perfect!! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to be able to copy, paste, and run your code.